# Redirecting stderr from a launcher

Tags: io-redirection, launcher

I've made a desktop launcher and I want to direct the stderr to a file, but the redirection file isn't even create:

```
/home/pl/my_thing.sh 2> /home/pl/stderr.txt
```

That's what I've got in my launcher, but when I run it, the command executes normally, but acts as though it ignores everything from `2` onward. If I copy and paste that line into the command-line, it works. So why not in my launcher?

Comment: A desktop launcher in what desktop? What do you mean by "ignores everything from `2` onward"?

Comment: @Kusalananda XUbuntu. I mean it acts like it's not there. It runs the command but the file isn't even created and the stderr is written to the terminal (when I select to run in one)

Comment: I suspect the launcher is not run by shell, so shell redirection does not work. Put it into the .sh file itself.

Comment: @9000 Looks like you're right. Putting the redirection into `/home/pl/my_thing.sh` was the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found in another case that when you click a `.desktop` file to run it, the `stdout` is `gnome-shell`, and the content is logged to `/var/log/syslog` on Ubuntu.

The file name maybe different on other OS.